# how to place image tags in a select imput bar

Tags: css

I have a select box below that works perfectly; I however want to place a little colour box in each of the option groups. I tried using a span tag within it but it does not seem to work.

I don't want to use anchor tags or images. I would prefer if possible just to have some kind of container tag.

I have enclosed my code below.

```
<select  name="search-legend">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1"<?= $this->ReturnSearchValue == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>> <span id="redbox"> </span>  value1 </option>
      <option value="2"<?= $this->ReturnSearchValue == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>> <span id="bluebox"></span>  value2 </option>
      <option value="3"<?= $this->ReturnSearchValue == "3" ? 'selected' : '' ?>> <span id="greenbox"></span>  value3 </option>

     </select>
```

**the css**

```
#redbox {
  background: red;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `<option>` is `HTML` not supported. You can style the `<option>`

HTML

```
<select  class="search-legend">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="" class="redbox"></option>
    <option value="" class="greenbox"></option>
    <option value="" class="bluebox"></option>
 </select>
```

CSS

```
.search-legend option.redbox{
    background:red;
}
.search-legend option.greenbox{
    background:green;
}
.search-legend option.bluebox{
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: thank you everyone for your kind assistance. warm regards andreea

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. The HTML spec. does not allow html markup inside an `<option>` element. My browser just ignored it. I think if you really want this you need to be thinking about a jQuery plugin or something. Maybe Google for 'jQuery plugin select with images'.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work in Firefox. But for those browser you have to use some JS libraries for ex: jQuery UI.

```
<select  name="search-legend">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option style="background-image:url(img1.png);" value="1"<?= $this->ReturnSearchValue == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>value1 </option>
  <option style="background-image:url(img2.png);" value="1"<?= $this->ReturnSearchValue == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>value2 </option>
  <option style="background-image:url(img2.png);" value="1"<?= $this->ReturnSearchValue == "3" ? 'selected' : '' ?>> value3 </option>
 </select>
```